# Splashscreen to check update on top of tabbarcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, splash-screen

I tried to load a splashscreen on top of a tabbarcontroller in my application.
No apple HIG references please, the aim of this splashscreen is to check for connectivity, then check for content update.

What's would be done in case of update Splashscreen -> update view -> tabbarcontroller
In case of nothing Splashscreen -> tabbarcontroller

I present the update view modaly from the splashscreen view controller.

I'm unable to have the splashscreen loaded each time the app is launched and when the app comes back from background.

on the appdelegate I use:

```
self.firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]
                            initWithNibName:nil
                            bundle:NULL];
self.secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]
                             initWithNibName:nil
                             bundle:NULL];
self.thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc]
                            initWithNibName:nil
                            bundle:NULL];
NSArray *twoViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc]
                               initWithObjects: self.firstViewController, self.secondViewController, self.thirdViewController, nil];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:twoViewControllers];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
self.ecranDemarrage = [[SplashViewController alloc] init];
    self.ecranDemarrage.showsStatusBarOnDismissal = YES;
    self.ecranDemarrage.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:self.ecranDemarrage animated:YES];
```

Well, the splashscreen is displayed after the tabbarcontroller... Not a good point.

I tried to launch on applicationdidbecomeactive notification, works but always shows the tabbarcontroller first then the splashscreen.

I tried to add the splashscreen view as a subview before making window visible, not much success either.

Could someone point me in the right direction in order to have the splashscreen loaded before anything else?

Comment: do u have any functionality on splash screen.. i mean any buttons or something for the user interaction..?

Comment: Only a yes / no alertview if there is an update available

Comment: try the below answer it will work.. presenting splashController before setting tabBarController to rootViewController.. once the splashController work is done set the tabBarController as rootViewController..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Did you add `Default.png` & `Default@2x.png`?? If yes then splash screen shows up automatically

2- You can also do this:(Mostly this is done when you have some functionality to perform after application launches, like you want to download data from web server or setup some application setting etc.)

Add you `splashcontroller` as a `rootcontroller` in `AppDelegate`, and then present the TabbarController as modal or again get the reference of AppDelegate in the SpalshController and change the `RootViewController` to `TabbarController`.

Comment: I could add Default.png but I need to have portrait and landscape ones  for as many localization that the application counts ;) 
With the splash screen controller, the image is cropped accordingly to the view
I will try to get the rootviewcontroller in the splash screen one

Comment: then first set your rootcontroller in AppDelegate to SpalshController and in splash controller, (using timer) swap the rootcontroller to TabbarController or present it as a Modal :)

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this ;)
Lot's of fun !

Comment: I managed to do exactly what I wanted. Thanks ÐąrέÐέvil. I didn't know that I could change root controller this way. Everyday I learn something.

Comment: Weird thing,
if I present the tabbar view controller as modal, I loose autorotation...

Comment: why don't you set tabbarcontroller to your rootcontroller again in AppDelegate

Comment: I did, but lost cross dissolve transition.
My fault, I did present as modal and set root at the same time by forgetting to add comment 
Now rotation is back :)