# First screen before tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I'm new to obj-C programming. I was interested how to make such app: I run it then it shows view controller with a button. I click this button and it shows tab bar controller. Should I show first screen as a modal view or are there other variants? Can you explain this process step by step.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551824/splashscreen-to-check-update-on-top-of-tabbarcontroler/13552108#13552108

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to have a `UINavigationController`. Then the `RootViewController` of this is your first view.

Then from the "first view" you can push the `TabBarController`.

You can hide the navigation bar if you don't want it but using the NavigationController just makes it so much easier to move between views.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that feature using delegate. Create LoginViewControler and define protocol in that. Implement that delegate method in your AppDelegate.m file. Following is sude code to achieve your desire functionality.

**// AppDelegate.h**

```
 @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,LoginViewControllerDelegate>{

 LoginViewController *loginViewController;
```

}

**// AppDelgate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
loginViewController.delegate = self;
self.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

```
-(void)loginButtonPressed {
[self.window setRootViewController:nil];
```

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

}

**//LoginViewController.h**

```
@protocol LoginViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
```

@required
- (void) loginButtonPressed;

@end

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController{
    id  delegate;

}

```
@property (retain) id delegate;

- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
```

@end

**//LoginViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
            [_delegate loginButtonPressed];
```

}